# Enable HTML anchor tag in pdf generator (FPDF)

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf, pdf-writer

I would like to insert a link into a PDF generated with FPDF. This is the current state of my code:

```
$link = 'www.blablabla.de';

$pdf->MultiCell("Please click the following link: <a href=".$link.">Click</a>. Thank you!");
```

I've also tried it in other ways, but it does not work out.

Hope someone can help me..

Comment: maybe this can help : http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto6.htm

Answer (score 1):

use this code. and also read fpdf manual. Code reference [Manual](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/write.htm)

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$pdf->Write(5,'Visit ');
// Then put a blue underlined link
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,255);
$pdf->SetFont('','U');
$pdf->Write(5,'your text','http://www.yourlink.com');
```

Comment: This is working, but how can I center the link in the generated pdf within the Write-method. There is nothing in the documentation..